Are compact metric spaces weak homotopy equivalent to a compact CW complex?
I was learning about CW-approximation and it tells us if you have a space $X$, then there is always a so-called CW-approximation of $X$, namely there is a map $f \colon Y \to X$ such that $Y$ is a CW complex and $f$ is a weak homotopy equivalence. We note here that $X$ is not a CW complex.
My question is now if $X$ were to be a compact metric space. Does it follow that it can be approximated by a compact CW complex, that is, again a weak homotopy equivalence $Y \to X$ such that $Y$ is a compact CW complex? I was going through the construction of the CW approximation, but couldn’t figure out why one would be able to only attach finitely many cells.

The fundamental group of any finite, connected CW complex is finitely-presented.
On the other hand, there are compact, path-connected metric spaces which do not have finitely-presented fundamental groups. In fact, the Hawaiian earring is a planar Peano continuum with uncountably-generated fundamental group.
For such an example $X$ there is not even any map $Y\rightarrow X$ from a finite CW complex $Y$ which induces an epimorphism on $\pi_1$.

For a simpler, but less satisfying example, the Cantor space $X$ is an uncountable compact subspace of the unit interval. It is totally path-disconnected, so has $\pi_0X\cong\mathfrak{c}$.
